# When I open a file in another directory it won't print the contents of the file but the directory?

Tags: python, path, directory

When I open my file (a .txt file) that is in another directory then print it, it only tells me the directory then: mode='r' encoding='cp1252' at the end in shell, not what is written in the file. It is not locked or anything either.

Here is my code:

```
import os
direct = ('C:\\Users\\Joshua\\Documents')
file =open(os.path.join(direct, "Test.txt"),'r')
print(file)
```

The file directory is correct and exists because I checked it using:

```
os.path.exists ('C:\\Users\\Joshua\\Documents')
```

in shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the proper method to read file content.

```
file = open(os.path.join(direct, "Test.txt"),'r')
print(file.read())
```